# UWP GetAsyncKeyState() from a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using the "DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Window)" template in vs2015. I want to get user's keystroke in every frame. So I tried to put GetAsyncKeyState() inside of the render-loop. The render-loop is running in a separate thread:

```
auto workItemHandler = ref new WorkItemHandler([this](IAsyncAction ^ action)
{
    // Calculate the updated frame and render once per vertical blanking interval.
    while (action->Status == AsyncStatus::Started)
    {
        critical_section::scoped_lock lock(m_criticalSection);
        Update();
        m_sceneRenderer->OnKeyDown();
        if (Render())
        {
            m_deviceResources->Present();
        }
    }
});

// Run task on a dedicated high priority background thread.
m_renderLoopWorker = ThreadPool::RunAsync(workItemHandler, WorkItemPriority::High, WorkItemOptions::TimeSliced);
```

m_sceneRenderer->OnKeyDown() is where I put GetAsyncKeyState(). But whenever I put m_sceneRenderer->OnKeyDown() inside the while loop, all the DirectX content will not be rendered. Also, m_renderLoopWorker will be nullptr and throw an exception when I close the application.

```
// Sample3DSceneRenderer.h, truncated
namespace UWP_DX11_XAML_
{
    class Sample3DSceneRenderer
    {
        Sample3DSceneRenderer(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ window);
        void OnKeyDown();
        Platform::Agile<Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^> m_window;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Sample3DSceneRenderer.cpp, truncated
UWP_DX11_XAML_::Sample3DSceneRenderer::Sample3DSceneRenderer(
        Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ window):
m_window(window)
{
}

void UWP_DX11_XAML_::Sample3DSceneRenderer::OnKeyDown()
{
     m_window.Get()->GetAsyncKeyState(Windows::System::VirtualKey::Control);
}
```

Calling other member functions of m_window can cause the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to setup a dedicated input thread using CreateCoreIndependentInputSource(CoreInputDeviceTypes::Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes::Touch | CoreInputDeviceTypes::Pen);

There's a sample here which demonstrates this option: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/LowLatencyInput

I also found these similar articles which discuss optimizing for low input latency.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/optimize-performance-for-windows-store-direct3d-11-apps-with-coredispatcher

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/12/18/optimizing-directx-apps-for-low-latency-input-and-longer-battery-life/#JPGhHjXExbySmTf7.97

Comment: CreateCoreIndependentInputSource() doesn't look like it handles keyboard events, just pen/touch/mouse. Can it do keyboard?